# Calling a static array from a dynamic memory

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation

So I was making a programm with a class bingocard and a class player. Each player can have a maxium number od bingocards which you give it in the constructor of the player class. In the constructor we also have a dynamic array where we save each bingocard which is a 4x4 matrix (2d array).

```
class Bingocard
{
private:
    unsigned int card[4][4];

public:
    Bingocard();
    Bingocard(unsigned int Card[4][4]);
    Bingocard(const Bingocard& Card);
    Bingocard operator=(const Bingocard& Card);
};

BingocardBingocard()
{
}

Bingocard::Bingocard(unsigned int Card[4][4])
{
for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
    for (int j=0; j<4; j++)
        card[i][j] = Card[i][j];
}

Bingocard::Bingocard(const Bingocard& Card)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            card[i][j] = Card.card[i][j];
}

Bingocard Bingocard::operator=(const Bingocard& Card)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            this->card[i][j] = Card.card[i][j];

    return (*this);
}

class Player
{
private:
    unsigned int maxNumberCards;
    Bingocard* cards;
    unsigned int numberCards;

public:
    Player(unsigned int k);
    void newCard(Bingocard* Card);
    ~Player();
};

Player::Player(unsigned int k)
{
    numberCards = 0;
    maxNumberCards = k;
    cards = new Bingocard[maxNumberCards];
}

void Player::newCard(Bingocard* card)
{
    if (numberCards < maxNumberCards) {
        cards[anzahlKarten] = *card; //Assign operator is triggered;
        anzahlKarten += 1;
    }
    else
        cout << "Maximum cards reached! Adding more cards is not possible now." << endl;
}

Player::~Player()
{
delete[] cards;
}
```

I have now that dynamic array called cards in the class Player and I want to access each of its elements but I dont know which command to use. I know I can make a function for example getElement and give it the row and column I want as parameters, but I was wondering if I can do that the same thing without a function. I tried **(cards[a])[b][c]** but it gives an error back.
I need this to work so I can check each number on the card for a bingo.

Comment: You can [overload the indexing `operator[]()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading).

Comment: `cards[a].card[b][c]` would work, except for the fact that `card` is private. An accessor function is not a bad idea in that case.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ if I want to overload that operator, should I do it in the Bingocard class or Player class. And does the [] refer to the dynamic array in this case?

Comment: @HeatTheIce I think in the `Player` class that holds `cards` actually. Or provide an extra wrapper for the `cards` array.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ so as return type I should have     unsigned int [4][4] ?

Comment: @HeatTheIce Probably better something like `int [4][4] &`. But I'd recommend using `std::array<int,std::aray::int,4>,4>` as member in `BingoCard` rather than the raw array. It will make your life easier.